# How can I remove the sticky taskbar at the top, to return to the old taskbar behavior?

Tags: feature-request

I just refreshed my screen and found a giant sticky task bar at the top of my screen. Is there a way to remove this, so that it will disappear as a I scroll down.

I prefer not to see it most of the time. In addition, it appears to be 30% longer than the previous taskbar.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @CodyGray.

Comment: Thanks to the removed link: user Profile > Edit Profile & Settings > Site Navigation. Check the box "Disable fixed site navigation."